# Goto на одну строку C#

Tags: c#

Вот допустим есть код:

Код1

Код2

Код3

Код1 код2 и код3 выполнились.

И здесь я уже ввожу goto(код1)
Но мне нужно чтобы только код1 выполнился и все остальные игнорировались. Как это сделать?

Comment: Выкинуть goto, сделать три фукции, вызвать `ф1(), ф2(), ф3(), ф1()`

Answer (score 1):

Если есть выбор в реализации, я предложил бы разбить Код1, Код2, Код3 по функциям и вызывать их при определённых условиях из какой-то главной функции (как написал [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167))

Если всё таки вам нужна реализация через goto, можно добавить статическую переменную, например:

```
bool shouldExecuteSection = true;
```

И общая идея будет следущая:

```
Код1: // метка, куда нужно вернуться
Код1
if (shouldExecuteSection)
{
    Код2
    Код3
}
shouldExecuteSection = false;
goto(Код1);
```

**Но всё же, настоятельно не рекомендую использовать goto**, так как это делает вашу программу непредсказуемой. Если это маленькая программа, это не очень замечается, но если приложение растёт в размерах, с разными модулями - время на отладку увеличивается в разы.

Answer (score -2):

У вас есть несколько кусков кода, и они в разных ситуациях выполняются по разному? К примеру можно вот так сделать:

```
public class SomeClass
{

private readonly Strategy _strategy;

public SomeClass(Strategy strategy) => _strategy = strategy;

public SomeMethod()
{
  if(_strategy.NeedCode1) Code1();
  if(_strategy.NeedCode2) Code2();
  if(_strategy.NeedCode3) Code3();
}

private void Code1()
{
//...
}

private void Code2()
{
//...
}

private void Code3()
{
//...
}
}

public class Strategy
{
  public bool NeedCode1 {get; set;}
  public bool NeedCode2 {get; set;}
  public bool NeedCode3 {get; set;}
}

static int Main()
{
   var some = new SomeClass(new Strategy{NeedCode1 = true});
   some.SomeMethod();
}
```

Но есть и другие решения. Всё зависит от контекста. Главное чтобы было удобно использовать, легко читать, не перегружать ответсвенностью.